# Tags/Documentation with SVN Project in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, documentation, eclipse-pdt

I've searched around with this and haven't found any clear answers.

I'm using Eclipse PDT. It seems that if I create a PHP Project, tags work (@todo, etc). However, if I create a project from SVN (still PHP based), tags don't work at all.

Does anyone know how to make tags and doc generation work on a per project basis and still import projects from a SVN repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh, I believe I have it.

As stated above:

> In the menus, Project -> Properties,
>   then select Task Tags in the left-hand
>   column, and check the "Enable
>   Searching for Task Tags" checkbox. You
>   may also need to check the "Enable
>   project specific settings" box.

But I also needed to do this:

> Project -> Configure -> Add PHP
>   Support

After refreshing the project, the Problems view filled up with all the FIXME @todo etc. Thanks so much! Have been trying to figure this out for a week!

Answer (score 1):

In the menus, Project -> Properties, then select Task Tags in the left-hand column, and check the "Enable Searching for Task Tags" checkbox. You may also need to check the "Enable project specific settings" box.

(This is for 3.5.1 Galileo; YMMV with other versions.)

Comment: Hmm, I thought I did that. I'll check again.